# Slickgrid Auto rendering

Tags: slickgrid

I have implemented slickgrid into my application. But the preblem is when i edit the values in particular row and scroll down it, the values has been reset. Could you please help me how to stop auto rendering in slickgrid

Thanks in Advance,
srini

Comment: How are you editing the values?

Comment: Getting the selected row's HTML attributes and appending text fields into the div. This is the way i'm editing the fields. When im scroll down the values which i have filled in the text fields are reset. Can you able to give me the solution

Comment: You cannot modify Slickgrid's DOM and expect it to retain those changes. Slickgrid uses virtual scrolling which means that it only ever renders the visible rows plus some extra for a buffer. When you scroll down, it takes the top rows (which are no longer visible) and reuses them by moving them to the bottom and replacing the content inside the cells. You need to update the SlickGrid's internal data structure to persist that information when scrolling. See here: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#updating-data